# Баг в настройке dell PowerConnect 3424

Tags: настройки, свич

Доброе утро, вчера столкнулся с такой проблемой: при настройке очередного dell свича, после того как прокинул влан, выдает ошибку, что нет такой команды.

В чем может быть проблема и как ее устранить? Или свичь на свалку?

После этих команд ведет себя нормально

```
vlan databasevlan 180
```

Но когда прописываю это.. пишет несуществующая команда.

```
interface vlan 180
```

с 20 свичей таких оказалось 4.

Вот скопировал конфиг:

> `console> enaconsole# confconsole(config)# aaa authentication login default lineconsole(config)# aaa authentication enable default lineconsole(config)# username admin password ******console(config)# exitconsole# confconsole(config)# line consoleconsole(config-line)# login authentication defaultconsole(config-line)# password ******console(config-line)# exitconsole(config)# line telnetconsole(config-line)# login authentication defaultconsole(config-line)# password ******console(config-line)# exitconsole(config)# vlan databaseconsole(config-vlan)# vlan 180console(config-vlan)# interface vlan 180% Unrecognized commandconsole(config-vlan)#`

Answer (score 1):

Ну что ж, смотрю никто так и не ответил, разобрался я в проблеме, может кому пригодиться..

Там из-за разных прошивок есть некоторые особенности, так что после console(config-vlan)# vlan 180 нужно выйти с vlana. (exit) и дальше уже прописывать interface vlan 180.